# Matlab low pass filter output initial/end value

Tags: matlab, filter, lowpass-filter

I have a signal with an unwanted oscillating carrier, shown in the blue curve. I made a low pass filter (5th order butterworth) and applied with `filtfilt` function, and low the filtered output is the red curve.

```
[b,a] = butter(5,.7);
y = filtfilt(b,a,y);
```

[image]
The red curve from x value 500 to the end is exactly what I wanted, however the initial oscillation is still there. It seems like the filter function tries to match the initial/end value of the filter input and output, thus the oscillation preserves. Is there a way to unmatch the initial value so I can get a smooth output without any oscillation?

Update:
I think my question wasn't clear. I want something like the black curve (hand drawing): completely remove the oscillation, and do NOT match the initial value. How can I do this? [image]

Comment: So you're looking for a [critically damped response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Critical_damping_.28.CE.B6_.3D_1.29)?

Comment: @FabianTamp Actually no, I simply want to remove the oscillation completely and retrieve the "average" trend curve. So I would like the red curve to start from the middle (something like value of 22) instead of the signal initial value (about value of 27). Are you saying a low pass filter won't be able to do that? What other method remove the oscillation?

Comment: Could you share the raw data vector `y` so we could try different approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When confronted with this problem, what I often end up doing is creating a start-up signal which precedes the filtered signal.

For a low pass filter that is a relatively easy task, but depends on your original signal. My initial attempt would be to reflect part of the signal with respect to the origin:

```
[b,a] = butter(5,.7);
N = 50; % change this to suit your needs
    yNew = filtfilt(b,a,[y(N:-1:1);y];
yNew = yNew(N+1:end);
```

This ensures that the start-up is minimal, and you can "hit the ground running".

Comment: It might be worth padding the signal at the end as well. Furthermore, you may use the function `padarray` for this purpose, it has several interesting padding options.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that what you're asking isn't possible.

All filters take some time to "warm up" - this is known as the 'rise time' of the filter. This occurs because an `n`-order filter performs a weighted average of the last `n` samples, and when the signal first starts, that backlog of samples isn't available.

The filter you've got there actually has a pretty good rise time - it only takes around 10 samples to start tracking the input properly.

The oscillations that occur are known as 'overshoot' - when designing a filter, there's a tradeoff between rise time and overshoot, you can't have a fast rise time and no overshoot. The wikipedia article on [damping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping) might be a good resource for you.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. So low pass filters won't give me what I need. Then what other methods can remove this oscillation for me? There must be a way, right? This is just a mathematical thing.

Comment: You can get rid of the oscillation if you critically damp your filter, but this will decrease the rise time.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my question wasn't clear to you, or maybe wasn't correct at all. I now updated it and I want something like the black curve, completely remove the oscillation and leave only the trend line. Critically damp will still give me the initial rise.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the previous answers and comments, it seems like filtering is not exactly the sought answer for this particular question.

Have you considered fitting the signal with some parametric curve? Since the sought curve lies amidst the signal (no "outliers"), it seems like least-squares fitting can do quite well.

```
% assuming y is your signal
% fit polynomial of degree Deg
Deg = 5; 
x = linspace(0,1, numel(y));
p = polyfit( x, y, Deg );
figure('Name','fit poly');
plot( y, '-+b');
hold all;
plot( polyval( p, x ), ':k', 'LineWidth', 1.2 );
```

I used `polyfit` to `Deg=5` in this example, but you may consider different functions and different degrees.

You might find `fit` a helpful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try sgolay filtering (order 1 should be enough) before applying the butter filter. Sgolayfilter fits the initial points with its underlying polynomial approximation (line for order 1).
See the example with something similar to your data

```
tt=0:1000;
toto=cos(.3*tt).*cos(tt*pi/4000)-tt/500+sin(pi*tt/1000);
[B,A]=butter(4,.02);
plot(tt,toto,tt,filtfilt(B,A,toto),'r',tt,filtfilt(B,A,sgolayfilt(toto,1,51)),'k');
```

Hope it may still help.

Answer (score 0):

Run the filter forward to generate the red curve. Then run the red curve through the filter again, this time backwards starting with the last value of the red curve. That will smooth out the transient at the beginning of the red curve.